# How can I tell my React app which component I want to update in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a React app that renders components from an array of objects stored in a Firestore document. It is essentially a social media app, and I am trying to develop the 'Like' button to update the 'likes' property on the firestore document for each user post. The problem I am encountering is that since the 'LiveFeed' renders all of the posts using .map, I am having trouble telling my function which post I want to update.

I am able to use the firestore.update method in my action to update all of the likes property on my "posts" collection, but I am not able to isolate a single one that a user would click 'like' on.

**Here is the POST component which renders all of the posts from the post collection in firestore using a map method in the parent component**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../../scss/styles.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {newLike} from '../../actions/postActions';
import moment from 'moment';

function Post(props){

  const { post, newLike } = props;
  console.log(post) //return

  function handleNewLike(post){
    const currentpost = post;
    newLike(post);
  }

    return(
      <div className="container section post">
        <div className="card post-card">
          <span className="card-title"><h5>{post.authorFirstName} {post.authorLastName}</h5></span>
          <div className="card-content center">
            <p className="black-text">{post.content}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="card-action">
            <button className="waves-effect waves-light btn" onClick={handleNewLike}>LIKE</button>
            <p>likes: {post.likes}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
              <p className="grey-text center">{moment(post.createdAt.toDate()).calendar()}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      newLike: (post) => dispatch(newLike(post))
    }
  }

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Post);
```

**Here is the action where I want to update a unique Post likes property (the first function is what creates a post**

```
import * as types from './../constants/ActionTypes';

export const createPost = (post) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    console.log(post)
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
    const authorId = getState().firebase.auth;
    firestore.collection('posts').add({
      ...post,
      authorFirstName: profile.firstName,
      authorLastName: profile.lastName,
      authorId: authorId,
      createdAt: new Date()
    }).then(()=> {
      dispatch({type: types.CREATE_POST, post});
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: types.CREATE_POST_ERROR, err});
    });
  };
};

export const newLike = (post) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore})  => {
    console.log(post)
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore.collection('posts').doc(post.id).update({
      likes: +1
    }).then(()=> {
      dispatch({type: types.NEW_LIKE, post});
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: types.NEW_LIKE_ERROR, err});
    });
  };
};
```

**Here is the component that maps the array of Posts to the DOM**

```
import React from 'react';
import Post from './Post';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



function LiveFeed(props){
  const { posts } = props;
  return(
    <div className="liveFeed">
      <div>
        {posts && posts.map(post => {
          return (
              <Link to={'/post/' + post.id} key ={ post.id }>
                <Post post={post}/>
              </Link>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default LiveFeed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `React.memo` for your `Post` component. And this will tell React to update component only if props have been changed:

```
const Post = React.memo(function Post(props) {
  /* only rerenders if props change */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was overlooking a simple mistake, and not passing the correct argument through the function